# Multiple Date Picker not working(Calendar not appear)

Tags: datepicker

I have form contain one date field and a button (Add date) when user click on the button a new date field appear but it doesn't work  i have problem in date picker

```
<div class="col-md-2 right-border" id="target">
    <div class="form-field field-date getdate">
        <input type="text" name="Departure-FlightMultiCity" id="Departure-FlightMultiCity" class="field-input calendar-input caneldar" placeholder="Departing" style="font-size:14px;font-family:FontAwesome;height:30px">
    </div>
</div>

<a id="AddAnotherFlight" class="awe-btn-lager fa fa-plus" style="margin-left:20px;cursor:pointer;font-size:14px;margin-bottom:10px;display:block">
    <b> Add another Flight</b>
</a>
```

Comment: We can not help you without some code

Comment: I have add my code

Comment: Can you please add the source code related to datepicker initialization, I guess this should be some JavaScript?

Comment: Please note when the user click on the add another flight button
a new date field will be added and will get new id="DepartureFlightMultiCity1" and 2,3,4,.... so on    
$( "#Departure-FlightMultiCity1" ).datepicker();

Comment: for clarification
when the page appear for  the first time the user will see only one date field 
then when he click on the add another flight button another date field will appear (i make a copy from the first field from html.append) and just the first  date field work !!